# What kind of tasks are available in UWP

Tags: task, uwp

I need advice about tasks in uwp. I want use tasks to download images from web and saving them to cache folder. How I must create them and wait for them if I want to pause/cancel them when application going to suspend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use methods of the type [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.105).aspx) to run those downloads on another thread in the app without getting a very complex code to maintain. You can create a download-method that get's the parameter to download and where to store it and either await it or just fire it and don't wait. You can also create a collection of Tasks first and then use `Task.WhenAll(collection)` to fire them all async.
This only works when the app is active, not when suspended. If you want it still downloading in suspended mode, use Joel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of using the [BackgroundDownloader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207126?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class. With this you can pass the URIs that you want to download and define the locations to which the files are to downloads are to be stored. It returns a DownloadOperation on which you can call Start, Pause, so on. It has some other members so you can see the progress of the download too.